# Unload AppDomain Assembly

Tags: c#

I want to read some information from a .Net assembly, then modify the DLL by appending a short sequence of characters.
The first part works fine, but the second step fails, as the assembly is still in use.
This is the case although I loaded the assembly in its own AppDomain and after I finished step 1 unloaded the AppDomain.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is to use something like [Cecil](http://mono-project.com/Cecil) that allows you to inspect and rewrite assemblies without loading them in the AppDomain.

Answer (score 2):

References from assemblies loaded into a separate AppDomain have a nasty habit of "leaking" into the parent AppDomain, especially if you're reflecting the assembly and exchanging Type information across the boundary. There are lots of "gotchas" with keeping assemblies isolated in AppDomains truly segregated.

However, there's good news: you probably don't need to worry about the assembly being unloaded in order to modify it on disk - just use shadow copying!  Create an AppDomainSetup instance, set its ShadowCopyFiles property to true, and pass it when you create the new AppDomain. This will cause the assembly to be copied to a temporary file before being loaded, keeping the original assembly unlocked and available for modification.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot unload an assembly without unloading the AppDomain:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173101(VS.80).aspx

> There is no way to unload an
>   individual assembly without unloading
>   all of the application domains that
>   contain it. Even if the assembly goes
>   out of scope, the actual assembly file
>   will remain loaded until all
>   application domains that contain it
>   are unloaded.

Are you sure that no other process or AppDomain is using the assembly?